# How to add selective nodes in the log file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am trying to perform a testing on a trained model.  I have restored the checkpoint in the session. The model has a lot of operations but I am only testing part of it.

I would like to see the op network that I am testing in the tensorboard, but currently, it's all entangled with all other operations that I do not want.

Is there any way to store the `tf.summary` for the selective operations that you are performing in the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of merging all summaries by `merged_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()`, you can merge the ops that you wanted like `merged_summary_group1 = tf.summary.merge([op1, op2, ...])`. After that, replacing all `merged_summary` in `sess.run` with `merged_summary_group1`.